# Visual Studio 2008 debugger detach

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

My Visual Studio debugger detaches every time when I try to access a property in a web application. I don't use Visual Studio's inner webserver, just the standard IIS. It seems like that property has somewhere a stack overflow

> (Server Application Unavailable)

, but I can't find it. There is an error message in the EventLog:

> aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: 5200) stopped unexpectedly

I've tried to delete all temp folder including ASP.NET temporary files, no change at all. I've tried to start

> devenv.exe /log

but in the log xml, there was hardly any exception. Is there any way to get that exception which causes the debugger to stop/detach?

Plus info is that another colleague can debug that property. I've tried to get his vssetting file, but no change.
thx

Comment: What's the code within the property?

Comment: it is a class with ~200 rows of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause of a sudden and unexpected debugger detach is a stack overflow in the debuggee process.  This can't be fixed by changing the settings in Visual Studio, only by changing / fixing the bug in the debugee process.

One thing you can do to help track down the problem is disable implicit property evaluation

- Tools -> Options
- Debugger -> General
- Unchecke "Enable implicit property and .ToString evaluation"

With this disabled the debugger will only execute properties that you explicitly ask it to.  This should help you out in narrowing down the problematic property / method.